# Eclipse launch existing launch-configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So i am writing an eclipse plugin, which adds a custom-launch action to the toolbar. It extends AbstractLaunchToolbarAction , thus it also has that dropdown menu with launch history and so on. This menue is filled up with actions, containing the lauch-configurations.

At this point, when i open dropdown menu and select one launch configuration from the history, it works fine and runs the configuration.

However, my aim would be to alter this behaivor, to do something more. 
My problem is that i cannot find the place where the launch configuration from the menu is processed, thus i cannot do anything with it...
So far i just create the menue by calling  the fillMenu(Menu m)

So my question is, how (in code) does eclipse proccess the exceution of the history launch-configuration? Where does the actual launching take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... The menu consists of Action elements, which have method 'run' ... This method gets called when the Action is clicked.